# How to make Chrome Extension available to testing, before production

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

When I need to make an Android App available in development, I use Play Console to do it, because this tool gives us an option to up the App in DEV to testing, before launching it in Production, that allows any user with link make a download of app by PlayStore to test it.

Is it possible, or exists any tool of Google that allow the same steps above, to deploy a Chrome Extension to testing, before launching it in Production, that can be accessed by any user with link to download and install it on Chrome browser?

P.S. I don't see the option in Chrome Web Store to up an extension to testing like in play console with apps.

Comment: No, you'll have to upload a [separate test extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/cws-dashboard-distribution/#publishing-a-test-version).

Comment: Hello @wOxxOm, is the test extension also go through the review process? what happens when I update the extension with bug fixes? will the testers receive it?

Comment: I don't work for the web store so I don't know if it's reviewed but probably yes.